# Embedding React app in another website with Google Tag Manager using <script>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-tag-manager

I have created React app. Now I want to integrate this App in multiple websites on a particular path using  and Google tag manager.
I.e., I have created `<script src="https://myreactapp/bundle.js"></script>`.
As per Google Tag manager, I have added this tag in **custom HTML** of my GTM account for a particular trigger(i.e. "https://myanotherwebsite.com/gtmscriptchanges").
Since it is a react appp, I have also included tags below along with this above script tag

```
  <div id="root"></div>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://myreactapp/bundle.js"></script>
```

Apart from this, I have also included https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gtm-module in my index.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import TagManager from 'react-gtm-module'

const tagManagerArgs = {
  gtmId: 'GTM-*****'
}

TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs)

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

After following all of the above steps, I should be able to see my react app at this location:https://myanotherwebsite.com/gtmscriptchanges, But unfortunately I am unable to! I am not getting any errors but also, I am not able to see new changes in my another website.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I just needed to add one route in react App.js

```
          <Route path='*' exact={true} component={Search} />
```

where Search is my base component.
For detailed Info: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/single-page-web-app-with-google-tag-manager/